# Trouble with 'fade in' effect on hover over text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a fade in effect on a word with just a letter showing at the beginning and the rest of the word is slide/fading in on hover.

I'm modifying a code in Sublime, I've managed to do it there locally and shows well in Chrome ([see a gif here](https://imgflip.com/gif/39xqzj)) but I cannot replicate it [in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raw2sqcm/1/) as well as have it on the other side, starting for the left towards the middle. Locally I've managed to do it just as in the .gif only from right to middle, for the other side is just as in the fiddle - with same classes applied to both sides.

```
    <div align='right' class='explore'>
<span class='info'>e</span><span class='hidden nameFull xplore'>xplore</span><span class="enterarrow"></span>

</div>

<div align='left' class='explore'>
<span class='info'><span class='hidden nameFull xplore'>explor</span>e</span><span class="enterarrow"></span>

</div>

span {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.enterarrow {
    background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/ErV.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 1vw;
    height: 1vw;
}

.explore:hover .xplore {
    width: 10vw;
    opacity: 1;
}

span.hidden {
    width: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I want it as in that gif, so that the rest of the text and arrow to detach from the margin and stick together with the letter 'e' while fading in, and the letter 'e' to sort of push it back to the margin when fading out.

I cannot find anything that can be the main factor for this behavior so please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the *fade in* effect by playing with `opacity` property. As for `slide` effect, you can make use of margin, padding, or the left properties.

In the demo below, I changed `padding-left` to achieve the slide effect.

```css
.wrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 250px;
  transition: padding-left 1.3s ease;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  padding-left: 150px;
}

.enterarrow {
  background-image: url(http://www.ladrianpop.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Asset-3.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  width: 1vw;
  height: 1vw;
}

.hidden-part {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1.3s ease;
}

.wrapper:hover .hidden-part {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  e<span class="hidden-part">xplore</span>
  <div class="enterarrow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Also see this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vodw7hab/1/).